# How to remove Advanced Mac Cleaner popups from the browser?

Tags: malware

When browsing, particularly in safari, I get really annoying tabs opening up offering me to download the Junk software Advanced Mac Cleaner. I tried to use malware bytes and ccleaner but it didn't help. Also get pages saying your computer is infected yada yada.

Anything else I can try?